# What is the SCSS equivalent of color="primary" in Ionic 4?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I am using this HTML syntax that produces the toolbar to be in my primary color and the text inside the toolbar to be in contrast with that color:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      GreenWalls Aplikace
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

[image]

My application will have many page's and I don't want to set all of the toolbar color's manually - instead I want to set this color inside `global.scss` file and apply it **automatically** and **globally**. This is what I have tried and didn't work so far ([from Ionic theming tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/colors)):

```
ion-toolbar {
  background: var(--ion-color-primary);
  color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
}
```

Result from the code above:

[image]

How can I achieve the same output in `SCSS` as using in `HTML color="primary"` in Ionic (using Angular framework)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot "--" before CSS properties name.

Try this :

```
ion-toolbar {
    --background: var(--ion-color-primary);
    --color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks - but I just copied it from Ionic4 docs ... see for yourself: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/colors

Comment: No problem ! You should read this page : https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables :)